# Does varchar's length have any effect on performance

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have discussions with our development staff over the use of VARCHAR columns as they define every varchar fileds as varchar(255),varchar(500),...  and much bigger than the maximum length of the field,
does varchar's length have any effect on performance in db2? We have find that it is recommended to use char instead of varchar for column of 30 bytes or less and our concern is about varchar fileds that are greater than 30 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing excessive column length is not a good idea. If you allow, let’s say, a `FirstName` column to have maximum length 500, you may find quite a long irrelevant story there eventually, because why not if it’s allowed :)

As for performance implications.
The only problem may be here, if [Extended row size](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0061057.html) is turned on for the database (you simply can’t create too “wide” table otherwise), and the total length of the row exceeds the tablespace page size. Some varchar column value gets out from the data page, and more IO will be needed to access such a row in future. You should keep in mind such a behavior. And the probability of such events is higher in case of uncontrolled varchar columns length.

Answer (score 0):

This can have an performance hit with ORGANIZE BY COLUMN tables. There is a limit in the total declared width that can be processed within the Columnar Data Engine, if this limit is breached in a query plan, the remainder of the query will be processed in the Row Data Engine.